# Is it a good idea to maintain a "trunk" VS project folder in addition to folder(s) for branches?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, svn-trunk

In using Visual Studio 2010 on PC clients in an SVN environment, is it reasonable to assume that each project really needs a "trunk" reference working copy in addition to any branches that may be in use? I don't see how a single, branch copy without a trunk could ever be properly reconciled back to the repository when merging branch changes back to trunk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct you need for every project (folder in the svn repsoitory) the default structure

```
  Project
    +-- trunk
    +-- tags
    +-- branches
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've got at least those basic folders down, but I was also asking about whether there should, as a matter of practice, always be a reference "trunk" project on a local VS2010 box *in addition* to any project folders specifically created for branches.

Comment: That depends on the strategy your are running. If you are running a stable-trunk strategy than yes otherwise you can use a different branch as the stable part. Furthermore if you have multiple parallel branches which needed to be hold based on maintenance etc. This can make it possible to get rid of a "trunk".